# nm uknown command line argument '-C'?

Tags: c++, macos, command-line, arguments, nm

I want to get a list of **demangled symbols** of my *object file* like

```
nm -C file.o
```

but my `nm` command has no `-C` argument? I am using a Mac and I guess the issue is a different, preinstalled version of `nm` than on my linux machine.

Is it possible on MacOS with the nm command to get the demangled symbols? If not how do you guys get this info on a Mac?

Comment: Did you try `man nm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
nm  file.o | c++filt
```

which yelds the same output.